# CGAffineTransform rotation

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics, cgaffinetransform

I have already drawn a bar chart using core graphics. (Figure 1)

[image]

And I need another bar graph as follows. I don't need to write another graph for this and I need to reuse the code I have already written. I guess there's a way to do this using rotation. But the trick is width and height are swapped in 2 charts. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If your output is a `UIImage` and you are displaying it using a simple `UIImageView`, you could adjust the image view's transform property like so:

```
#define degreesToRadians(x) (M_PI * x / 180.0)
[myImageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(90))];
```

Doing this would properly adjust the height and width of the `UIImageView`. For example if the image view starts out 100x200 after this rotation its frame will be 200x100 and the image within it will rotate as well.

Then you could even adjust the anchor point to rotate from using:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
[[myImageView layer] setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)];
```

The `CGPoint` (0.5, 0.5) refers to the center of the image view.